# how to print just the values of the tuple element values in the dictionary while iterating through it

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

```
d = {'k1':1,'k2':[(2,4),(6,8),(10,12)],'k3':3}

for (a,b) in d.values():
    print (a)
    print (b)
```

when i try this it says

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-49-81a0566d1778> in <module>()
  ----> 1 for (a,b) in d.values():
  2     print (b)
  3     print (a)

 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

i just want to print the output as

2

4

6

8

10

12

Comment: Not all `dict` values in your example is `tuple`, thats why you getting this error.

Comment: @bro-grammer. First off, awesome user name. Second, nitpick, but not every value is a list containing tuples, or iterable containing two-element iterables.

Answer (score 1):

Since your dictionary contains both a list of tuples (which you want to flatten), and integers:

```
d = {'k1':1,'k2':[(2,4),(6,8),(10,12)],'k3':3}
```

you have to check for the type first before flattening your list, and then looping over its contents:

```
for (key, value) in d.items():
    if type(value) is list:
        # flatten the list of tuples into a list of ints
        # by applying `itertools.chain` on the unpacked (*) list
        # of tuples
        flattened = itertools.chain(*d[key])
        for num in flattened:
            print(num)
```

Note: to flatten your list, you need to import `itertools`, and unpacking works in Python 2.7+ and Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
# for key,val in d.items(): # python 3 version
for key,val in d.iteritems(): # go through all of key, values of d
    if isinstance(val, list): # check if they are a list/array
        for tup in val: # if they are, go through all of them
            if isinstance(tup, tuple):
                for num in tup: # don't assume they are all 2 number tuples
                    print("{0}\n".format(num)) # print each with an extra new line
```

You are assuming that all the dict values are all tuples. Try assuming a lot less about them and make sure you check their types. By assuring that it is a list you can then know you can loop over the list. After that make sure all of the elements in the list are tuples then iterate through all the numbers in the tuple and print (this also allows you to print tuples which have more than 2 numbers.